# I make a 'Hero' folder in 'components' in src , but when i try to import it in App.js it shows an error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, import, syntax-error

[This is the error, what I m trying to say in the title. please help to sort out that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Xim.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to import your component Hero, like `import Hero from './your folder/yourComponent'`.
hope that helps!

Comment: done this but it wont help

Comment: Line 6:11:  'Hero' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
ERROR in [eslint]
src\App.js
  Line 6:11:  'Hero' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack compiled with 1 error

Comment: if you can, try import {Hero} from './components/Hero/Hero.jsx' I think it is not defined because it is not imported in your App.js